# Plotting issue with Python IDLE

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am a beginner at python and am facing an issue with seeing plots in Python IDLE. The code runs and I get the following answer.

```
>>> plt.plot(x)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f8d1c342550>]
```

The Python Launcher starts jumping as soon as the above response is obtained and continues jumping for about 1-2 minutes. I don't see any image btw. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.plot()` creates the plots requested and returns to you said objects. You can then interact with them to see what data they hold, or change their properties. For example, colour, line width, etc.

```
>>> line, = plt.plot(x)
>>> type(line)
<class 'matplotlib.lines.Line2D'>
>>> line.set_linewidth(5)
```

**In order to see the plot**, you need to call

```
plt.show()
```